# Show executable files and run

Tags: bash, shell, unix, debian

I need advice with my program. In bash I need show executable files in directory with index and then run the files by the index. It is possible?

Thank you for replies

Comment: so you want to filter on the index and run specific indices OR just run all the executable files in the directory?

Answer (score 1):

The find command seems a bit complicated but very useful :

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -a=rx -exec echo Exec {} \;

- -maxdepth 1  :Descend at most levels 1
- -type f      :Only regular file (not directory)
- -perm -a=rx  :read and executable for owner
- -exec Exec {} \; :for each file found do echo Exec file ;

**Test :**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -a=rx -exec echo Exec {} \;   
Exec ./kl.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all executable files in a directory, you can try:

```
ls -l | awk '$1~"-rwxr-xr-x"{ print $9 }'
```

this command will print names of files with `-rwxr-xr-x`. You can rearrange it to suit your needs.

When you have the desired list of executables files, run them:

```
for i in $( ls -l | awk '$1~"-rwxr-xr-x"{ print $9 }' ); do ./$i; done
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is brittle. In this case a file would have to be executable for owner, group, and world --- which may or may not be the right thing. Why not use `find -executable` instead? Or `[ -x $file ]` in the loop? Others here may also complain about using backticks instead of `$(...)`.